# How to find the number of positive or negative real factors by using descartes' sign rule?

Tags: polynomials

I have a problem about finding the number of positive or negative factors of polynomial.

Here is the question:

How many positive or negative real factors from this polynomial?

$$2x^4-3x^3-17x^2+27x-9$$

It says that we can use Descartes' sign rule to find the number of positive or negative factors from here. But, I didn't understand how to apply it to find the answer.

Can anybody explain me how to use this rule?

Thanks

Comment: How do you define positive and negative for polynomials?

Comment: From my prior knowledge, if f(a) =0, then a is positive real factor for f(x), and if f(-a)=0, then -a is negative real factor for f(x)

Comment: I don't think so. That would be a strange definition. For example take $f(x)=x+1$. By your definition $-1$ is positive and negative real factor of $f$.

Comment: The definition is f(x) have factor (x-a), iff f(a)= 0. Is it more clear now? Thanks

Comment: I know what a factor is but I don't think that you would define a total order on $\mathbb R[X]$.

Comment: The rule is even more strange: Descartes´ rule of sign is used to determine the number of real zeros of a polynomial function. It tells us that the number of positive real zeroes in a polynomial function f(x) is the same or less than by an even numbers as the number of changes in the sign of the coefficients.


..I really don't understand about 'the number of changes in the sign of coefficients'. Thanks

Comment: Suppose, the polynomial is $$x^5-4x^4+3x^3+2x^2-7x+9$$ (It is important that the powers are sorted!). The signs of the coefficients are $+,-,+,+,-,+$. (If a $0$ appears, no sign is noted). The sign changes $4$ times from $+$ to $-$ or vice versa. So, the polynomial must have $4$,$2$ or no positive roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what you mean by positive or negative factors - Descartes rule of signs allows you to conclude some things about roots of real polynomials.

In this case, you have $p(x)=2x^4-3x^3-17x^2+27x-9$, which has exactly $3$ sign changes, which means it either has $1$ or $3$ positive roots.

Further, $p(-x) = 2x^4+3x^3-17x^2-27x-9$, which has exactly **one** sign change, so the original polynomial must have exactly $1$ negative root.  $0$ is not a root.

Thus we have from Descartes the situation where either
(a) we have $1$ positive and $1$ negative root (and the two remaining roots are complex conjugates) or
(b) we have $3$ positive and $1$ negative roots.

If you would like to get more conclusive, we must do a bit more work. Checking the sign of $p(x)$ at a few points often gives enough information to conclude on one case or the other.  Frankly, in this case it is not hard to find all the roots if you notice $p(1)=p(3)=0$, so not worth the while to pursue Descartes anymore.